# RoR: Postgres Timestamp without timezone error (sum)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, sum

I am using Postgres with my Rails application and I am trying to get sum of projects by their created date (which is a datetime attribute) in order to render the data on my chart:

```
t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
```

In my model (project.rb):

```
def self.created_at(date) 
 where("date(created_at) = ?", date).sum(:created_at)
end
```

JS for my chart:

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
      global: {
      useUTC: false
      }
    });
    var myChart = Highcharts.chart('applications_by_date', {
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: true
      },
      series: [{
      data: <%= (9.weeks.ago.to_date..Date.today).map { |date| Project.created_at(date)}.inspect %>
      }]
    });
  });
 </script>
```

But I get the following error I can't resolve so far...

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function sum(timestamp without time zone) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT SUM("projects"."created_at") FROM "projects" WHERE (d...
```

**EDIT:**

With groupdate gem:

@project_dates = Project.all.group_by_month(:created_at).count

Then in chart

data: <%= @project_dates %>

This shows the data correctly but can't get the dates to show on x axis?

[image]

EDIT: Groupdate gem query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, DATE_TRUNC('month', "projects"."created_at"::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/UTC')::date AS date_trunc_month_projects_created_at_timestamptz_at_time_zone_e FROM "projects" WHERE ("projects"."created_at" IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('month', "projects"."created_at"::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/UTC')::date
```

Result:

```
 {Sat, 01 May 2021=>144, Tue, 01 Jun 2021=>40, Thu, 01 Jul 2021=>8, Sun, 01 Aug 2021=>1, Wed, 01 Sep 2021=>0, Fri, 01 Oct 2021=>0, Mon, 01 Nov 2021=>0, Wed, 01 Dec 2021=>0, Sat, 01 Jan 2022=>8}
```

Comment: A sum over a timestamp does not make sense (at least to me). What's the sum of Monday at 14:00 and Thursday at 17:00?

Comment: Focus on asking about what the code is actually supposed to do - IE what is the data you expect to be passing to the graph and not the how. This code here is pretty far off from what you want to be doing as you're creating n+1 queries for each item by iterating across it and then selecting a SUM  which is extremely inefficient (besides the fact that it doesn't actually work). On Postgres you can group by day, week, hour, etc by using the [date/time functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html) with SQL strings or Arel or by using the groupdate gem.

Comment: What you want is something more like `Project.where(created_at: 9.weeks.ago...).group('date(project.created_at)').count` which will give you a hash with dates as keys and a count for each day.

Comment: @max Thanks for feedback (everyone)! I went with groupdate gem as you suggested and it works to get the right data but how to get the months to display on the x axis and in the tooltips correctly? (my code for the chart is same as in the question) Thanks again!

Comment: What are the keys in the `@project_dates` hash? Can you show us the query generated by the groupdate gem?

Comment: I might have been jumping the gun slightly - maybe grouping by something like `date_trunc('month', project.created_at)` is a better fit then the groupdate gem as it will give you a timestamp that you can then format however you want.

Comment: @max thanks but I think groupdate is close the mark? I put query and results in question...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it. Here is the answer for anyone who needs it. Used groupdate gem as suggested.

In my controller action:

```
@project_dates = Project.all.group_by_month(:created_at, format: "%b %Y").count
```

In the view...

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
      global: {
      useUTC: false
      }
    });
    var myChart = Highcharts.chart('applications_by_date', {
      xAxis: {
        categories: <%= raw @project_dates.keys.to_json %>
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: [{
        data: <%= raw @project_dates.values.to_json %>
      }]
    });
  });
</script>
```

Result:

[image]

Hope it helps someone. Thanks for your help @max. If you think this could refactored better please let me know

Comment: There is a lot of redundant code here. You can just use `window.months = <%= raw @project_dates.keys.to_json %>` and `window.total_projects = <%= raw @project_dates.values.to_json %>`. You don't need the loop or to use JSON. parse on the client side since you can simply output JSON from the server and any valid JSON is valid Javascript.

Comment: Thanks! It works just doing this too...`categories: <%= raw @project_dates.keys.to_json %>` and `data: <%= raw @project_dates.values.to_json %>` I'll edit the answer.